# Pegar rango de datos al final de una tabla VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hola espero me ayuden con lo siguiente, tengo una tabla "transaccion" en la "Hoja1" la cual alimento de datos que tengo en la "Hoja2" la idea es que se copie el rango de datos de la Hoja2 y lo pegue justo debajo de la tabla en mi Hoja1. Al intentar hacerlo solo logra pegar la primera fila pero falla cuando es mas de una fila de datos ya que solo sigue pegando una sola fila. Agradezco me ayuden. Muestro lo que llevo:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim newrow As ListRow
Dim Text1 As String
Dim Text2 As String
Dim Text3 As String



Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set newrow = ws.ListObjects("transaccion").ListRows.Add

FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


With newrow


Text1 = Worksheets("Hoja2").Range("a2").Value
Text2 = Worksheets("Hoja2").Range("b2").Value
Text3 = Worksheets("Hoja2").Range("c2").Value


  .Range(1) = Text1
  .Range(2) = Text2
  .Range(3) = Text3


  
End With
 


End Sub
```

[image: Hoja 1]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un pantallazo de ambos conjuntos de datos? No es necesario que sean datos reales, pero sí que tengan la misma estructura

Comment: Listo ya puse los capture de los datos para que puedas mirar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes copiar y pegar el rango ya que tienen el mismo formato.

```
Sub test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim UF As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja2")
    UF = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A2:C" & UF).Copy
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1")
    UF = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A" & (UF + 1)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excelente era justo lo que necesitaba.. Muchas gracias :)